# ::moz-selection does not apply to input elements

Tags: css, input, mozilla, element

Is there anyway I can get ::moz-selection applied to input elements, even if I have to edit some file in userChrome.css, userContent.css or some similar file?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of an input is not a text-node in the DOM, therefore CSS-selectors will not be able to target it.

Answer (score 0):

According to this question: [textarea::selection and ::-moz-selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043695/textareaselection-and-moz-selection) it's not possible. Maybe it will be in future browsers.

Comment: how about some configuration file inside Firefox/XUL folders? or is it  bound to the OS?