# How to change background color of selected text in a textbox?

Tags: css

Is there a way to change the color of the selection highlighting in text boxes?
Can i do it using CSS?

Comment: Do you mean a method of applying `::selection { background: }` to text input fields?

Comment: Please, clarify your question. Do you want background of selected text inside a textbox, or highlighting around the textbox when it is in focus?

Comment: As Said, please explain furhter what you need. Add a jsfiddle or give us some code or an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and yes.

You can use CSS pseudo class `:focus`

**Example:**

```
input:focus{
    border: 5px solid blue;
    background: green;
}​
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mLpg3/1/)**

Comment: You have two different "borders" in this demo. One is a border property set by you, and the other one is a default outline property set by the browser.

Comment: i ma looking for the text selection highlighting. No the focus highilght of the element

Answer (score 3):

There is a CSS3 property for selected text (::selection), but it does not work inside the input or textarea tags in Chrome or Safari. It only works in Firefox.

See [textarea::selection and ::-moz-selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043695/textareaselection-and-moz-selection)

Comment: i ma looking for the text selection highlighting. No the focus highilght of the element