# How to stop text highlight in HTML form fields

Tags: javascript, css, highlight, html-input, form-fields

After spending some time on Google I came here to get solution.
What I have to do is to stop the text highlight of an input field(HTML form fields) when user select using cursor. If user tries to select whole or part of text in an input field cursor should stop at the index where user starts the mouse left click. Something like this

**This should not**

[image]

**This should**

[image]

User should be able to locate the cursor in any index user wants but user should not be able to highlight text. I am not pro-expert in CSS. Any solution for this? JS solution would be the usage of setSelectionRange or createTextRange.

Any best CSS or JS solution please.

Comment: May I know why this question is being down-voted?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599585/styling-the-selection-color-of-an-input-type-text-possible

Comment: @w4rumy Thanks to pointed out. I was searching on Google for long time  and I could not find that answer. By the way please understand my question is not to change the highlight color. STOP TEXT BEING HIGHLIGHTED AND KEEP THE CURSOR IN THE INDEX WHERE STARTED TO HIGHLIGHT. I hope you didn't misunderstand. Thanks for Subhajit, I will check your solution.

Comment: if you (could) set the Highlight color to the background color of the textbox, it looks like not beeing highlighted.

Comment: @w4rumy if the user clicks in backspace or delete key what will happen? User have no awareness whether the text is being highlighted or not. Accidently if user clicks on backspace or delete it will remove all the text highlighted even though highlight is not shown. That is the reason stop highlight and keep the cursor at that index

Comment: I thought you have already a solution that your text gets unselected after the user has selected it, and you just want to avoid the color the user sees during selecting text?

Comment: may be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319126/prevent-highlight-of-text

Answer (score -1):

I hope its not possible to stop the highlight, well instead you can apply a trick to change the background color of the highlight to the textfield background color.

When the background colors would be same then it would not be highlighted, here ios the code to achieve the same :-

[View Demo at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ACpPF/).

**CSS**

```
input::selection {
background: #fff; 
}
input::-moz-selection {
background: #fff; /* Firefox lower versions */
}
```

Comment: This is not working in Chrome and Internet Explorer. It seems like only Firefox supports this.

Comment: This is working but in case if the user clicks on backspace or delete button it removes the text since text is being highlighted but highlight is not visible.. :(